# Mule CXF SOAP service - Validate against XSD and send custom response instead of Soap fault

Tags: web-services, soap, wsdl, mule, cxf

I have a Mule flow where I exposed a SOAP service using Mule's CXF inbound endpoint. I configured `validationEnabled="true"` and also `wsdlLocation="path-to\my\wsdl"`. With this configuration of CXF inbound endpoint, it is able to validate the incoming SOAP request and throw a SOAP fault in case there are schema validation errors. So far so good.

Now I want to customise the SOAP Fault response in case of schema validation errors.

I don't want to send SOAP Fault at all, instead I would like to send something like below in the response body

```
<errorCode>123</errorCode>
<errorDescription>some error description</errorDescription>
```

Can any one please tell me how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are exposing a SOAP web service and want to have a validation of incoming SOAP message against the schema and put custom message, then one of the best way is to use `mulexml:schema-validation-filter`

for example the following code :-

```
<mulexml:schema-validation-filter name="Schema_Validation" schemaLocations="yourSchema.xsd" returnResult="true" doc:name="Schema Validation" />  

<flow name="ServiceFlow" >
  <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="mainData" doc:name="HTTP Connector"/>
      <message-filter  onUnaccepted="ValidationFailFlow" doc:name="filter to validate xml against xsd" throwOnUnaccepted="true" >
        <filter ref="Schema_Validation"/>
     </message-filter> 
   <cxf:jaxws-service  serviceClass="com.test.services.schema.maindata.v1.MainData" validationEnabled="true" doc:name="SOAP"/>
   <component class="com.test.services.schema.maindata.v1.Impl.MainDataImpl" doc:name="JavaMain_ServiceImpl"/>
  </flow>
```

and the create a sub flow to create your custom message

```
<errorCode>123</errorCode>
<errorDescription>some error description</errorDescription>
```

:-

```
<sub-flow name="ValidationFailFlow" >
        <logger message="SOAP Request is not valid!!" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        <set-payload value="&lt;errorCode&gt;123&lt;/errorCode&gt;&lt;errorDescription&gt;Soap Validation fail!!!/errorDescription&gt;" doc:name="Set Payload" mimeType="application/xml"/>
 </sub-flow>
```

So now if validation is failing then it will route to your sub flow and show your custom message
note, you can create your custom message using set payload or Java class or XSLT or anything you wish :)
for more reference on `mulexml:schema-validation-filter` refer :-  https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/schema-validation-filter